# json returns empty array even though data is present in db - Android

Tags: php, android, json

I'm retrieving product details from woocommerce database,which is very vast.

Json is returning the array of products for the first time.But, when I reload the same page then it is empty.

Error log:

**Json response** for the *1st time*

```
07-25 10:49:08.010  24512-24726/com.example.images E/result﹕ {"file":[{"ID":"1","product_name":"Cake1"},{"ID":"2","product_name":"Cake2"},{"ID":"3","product_name":"Cake3"},{"ID":"4","product_name":"Cake4"},{"ID":"5","product_name":" Cake5"},{"ID":"6","product_name":"Cake6"},{"ID":"7","product_name":"Cake7"},{"ID":"8","product_name":"Cake8"},{"ID":"9","product_name":"cake9"},{"ID":"10","product_name":"cake10"},{"ID":"11","product_name":"Blackforest cake"},{"ID":"12","product_name":"Chocolate truffle cake"},{"ID":"454","product_name":"star cake"},{"ID":"67","product_name":"Vanila cake"},{"ID":"787","product_name":"Butterscotch cake"},{"ID":"121","product_name":"Half kg cake"},{"ID":"787","product_name":"Strawberry Cake"},{"ID":"77","product_name":"Vanilla Cake"},{"ID":"712","product_name":"cake 12"},{"ID":"714","product_name":"Half kg chocolate cake"},{"ID":"888","product_name":"Half kg Pineapple cake"},{"ID":"777","product_name":"BARBIE DOLL CAKE"},{"ID":"45","product_name":"BLUE CAKE"},{"ID":"50","product_name":"CHOCOLATE CREAM CAKE"},{"ID":"499","product_name":"ROUND BUTTER SCOTCH CAKE"},{"ID":"44","product_name":"PRINT CAKE"},{"ID":"58","product_name":"TRUFFLE CAKE"},{"ID":"862","product_name":"CREAMY CAKE"},{"ID":"86","product_name":"FRUIT CAKE"},{"ID":"487","product_name":"FULL CHOCOLATE CAKE"},{"ID":"872","product_name":"STRAWBERRY CAKE"},{"ID":"7845","product_name":"HEART CHOCOLATE CAKE"},{"ID":"5545","product_name":"VANILLA CHOCOLATE CAKE"}]}
```

**Json response** for the *2nd time*

```
07-25 10:49:24.290  24512-24679/com.example.images E/result﹕ {"file":[]}
```

I've tried to print the Error in php(used all possible statements), but it doesn't print anything in log.

Tried adding `Content-type` but no use.

php code:

```
<?php  
    ini_set('display_errors',1);  
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    include "db/db_connection.php";
    $term_id = $_POST['term_id'];
     //   header('Content-Type: application/json');

  $result =  $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT  `ID`,`post_title`,`post_content`,`post_excerpt`,`guid` FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='product' and post_status='publish' and ID IN(SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN(?) and term_taxonomy_id IN(SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy
            where taxonomy='product_cat'))");

  $result->execute(array($term_id));    
  $i=0;
  $file = array();

  if($result->rowCount()) 
  {
        while($fileName = $result->fetch()) 
      {
          $file[$i]['ID']= $fileName['ID']; 
          $file[$i]['product_name']= $fileName['post_title']; 
          $i++; 
      }
  } 
    echo json_encode(array('file'=>$file));

?>
```

db/db_connection.php:

```
<?php
   $host ="localhost";
    $db_name ="woocommerce";
    $db_username = "root";
    $db_password = "";  

    $dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$host;charset=utf8", "$db_username", "$db_password");   
    $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
    $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

?>
```

Android receiving json:

```
try
            {
                Log.e("result",result);
                JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                String data = json_data.getString("file");
                JSONArray json_data1 = new JSONArray(data);

                for (int i = 0; i < json_data1.length(); i++)
                {
                    json_data = json_data1.getJSONObject(i);

                    String product_name= json_data.getString("product_name");
                    String Id= json_data.getString("ID"); 
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
            }
```

Edit 1:

Http request-

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("term_id", ""+term_id)); 

            try
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false"); 
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.000.0.000/Prabs/Products.php"); 
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            }
```

Edit 2:

`term_id` was assigned to `0` as I am sending the `term_id` through `SharedPreference`

Now `term_id` is passed through intent,Even though error persist :(

**LOG**

```
07-25 12:44:27.890    4576-4788/com.example.images E/term_id to server﹕ 45
07-25 12:44:01.500    4576-4883/com.example.images E/result﹕ {"file":[{"ID":"1","product_name":"Cake1"},{"ID":"2","product_name":"Cake2"},{"ID":"3","product_name":"Cake3"},{"ID":"4","product_name":"Cake4"},{"ID":"5","product_name":" Cake5"},{"ID":"6","product_name":"Cake6"},{"ID":"7","product_name":"Cake7"},{"ID":"8","product_name":"Cake8"},{"ID":"9","product_name":"cake9"},{"ID":"10","product_name":"cake10"},{"ID":"11","product_name":"Blackforest cake"},{"ID":"12","product_name":"Chocolate truffle cake"},{"ID":"454","product_name":"star cake"},{"ID":"67","product_name":"Vanila cake"},{"ID":"787","product_name":"Butterscotch cake"},{"ID":"121","product_name":"Half kg cake"},{"ID":"787","product_name":"Strawberry Cake"},{"ID":"77","product_name":"Vanilla Cake"},{"ID":"712","product_name":"cake 12"},{"ID":"714","product_name":"Half kg chocolate cake"},{"ID":"888","product_name":"Half kg Pineapple cake"},{"ID":"777","product_name":"BARBIE DOLL CAKE"},{"ID":"45","product_name":"BLUE CAKE"},{"ID":"50","product_name":"CHOCOLATE CREAM CAKE"},{"ID":"499","product_name":"ROUND BUTTER SCOTCH CAKE"},{"ID":"44","product_name":"PRINT CAKE"},{"ID":"58","product_name":"TRUFFLE CAKE"},{"ID":"862","product_name":"CREAMY CAKE"},{"ID":"86","product_name":"FRUIT CAKE"},{"ID":"487","product_name":"FULL CHOCOLATE CAKE"},{"ID":"872","product_name":"STRAWBERRY CAKE"},{"ID":"7845","product_name":"HEART CHOCOLATE CAKE"},{"ID":"5545","product_name":"VANILLA CHOCOLATE CAKE"}]}



07-25 12:44:09.690    4576-5140/com.example.images E/term_id to server﹕ 44
07-25 12:44:11.560    4576-5140/com.example.images E/pass 1﹕ connection success
07-25 12:44:11.740    4576-5140/com.example.images E/result﹕ {"file":[]}
```

Comment: if you have curl installed, check output of `curl --data 'term_id=id' url_of_php_file` multiple times and see if response comes exactlythe same or not

Comment: Yes @anonymous. I've executed your command continuously for 20 times,it gives the same output

Comment: you may be having a problem with params.add() make sure that params.add() is executed every time and make sure it passes term_id, tell  me what you notice after debugging

Comment: then the problem is not in your php code, make sure data is posted to the url correctly and can you post your java code for http request

Comment: Sure @AhmadAlsanie ,am editing the question anonymous

Comment: you are right @AhmadAlsanie.. term_id is going as '0' for the next time.am keeping this term_id in sharedpreferences, I'll send it with intent now.

Comment: Ohh no...Even though it is giving blank @AhmadAlsanie  .. :(

Comment: could you please post the whole code

Comment: at least you find out that there is a problem with term_id now you have to figure a way to pass it in the right way

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie you are right..The issue was only with sending term_id,It took so long to alter all pages and testing them.Now everything works fine.If  you could post an answer then I'll accept it.Thank you so much for guiding me anonymous

Comment: NP glad I could help, and I posted my answer below so it could help others that faced the same problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be having a problem with `params.add()` make sure that `params.add()` is executed every time and make sure it passes `term_id`.

For somehow your application is not setting `term_id` correctly at the second request, you just have to figure out a way to get its value and pass it correctly.